# Stop inheriting web.config from parent ASP.NET application in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config

We have deployed an ASP.NET Website (App 1) in IIS 7.5. Then under that application create another ASP.NET application (App 2). But in App 2, I don't want to inherit the `web.config` from App 1.

If I try to do the following in App 1's, `web.config`:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> 
    <configSections> 

    <!-- etc -->

    </configSections>
</location>
```

it reports the error:

> **Config Error** The configuration section 'configSections' cannot be
>   read because it is missing a section
>   declaration

If I try to do:

```
<remove name = "system.web.extensions" />
```

it still reports the same error:

Comment: Just to add to above, APP 1 (parent) is using .net 3.5 framework while APP 2 (child) is using .net 2.x framework.

Comment: .net 3.5 runs ontop of the .net 2 framework.

Answer (score 7):

If you can deploy your child application to a separate website (same machine, different port), [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting) may be able to help with this.

The solution is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087162/run-two-web-sites-on-same-port-on-iis-7-5).  First, install [ARR](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting).  Then, configure your "child" application on a website that listens on a non-standard port.  Next, configure a rewrite rule on the "parent" application's web site that matches the original path to the "child" application.  Have this rule forward the request to the newly created website listening on the new port.

I would post an example, but I expect it is fairly straightforward to see how this would work by looking at [the post referenced above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087162/run-two-web-sites-on-same-port-on-iis-7-5).

Comment: this is a great solution for something like a Wordpress virtual directory which is hosted in the root of a site with a complex web.config

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

For those who could not get the location path solution working you might have forgotten to close the location elements tag (if you just edited the web.config in a text editor on the server). Here is an example:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
 ...
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
 ...
  </connectionStrings>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.web>
 ...
  </system.web>
 ...
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Notice that configSections and connectionStrings should not be in the location element which is probably the reason the OPs attempt did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following link:

http://www.kowitz.net/archive/2007/05/16/stopping-asp-net-web-config-inheritance

I can vouch for this as working as I have done this in the past.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, this <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> doesn't work for <configSections>.

Answer (score 0):

You can't wrap the whole `<configSections>` configuration element in a `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">`. This isn't supported in ASP.NET (yet).

From the documentation:

> [SectionInformation.InheritInChildApplications Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.inheritinchildapplications.aspx)
>
> The InheritInChildApplications
>   property applies only to
>   location-specific configuration
>   settings.

Also:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates
>   whether the settings that are
>   **specified in the associated configuration section** are inherited
>   by applications that reside in a
>   subdirectory of the relevant
>   application.

`<configSection>` elements are special and are not configuration settings as such. They are used to define the handlers for configuration settings.

If you need to remove a conflicting configuration `<section>` from a child application you can do this in the child application's `web.config` file with the `<remove>` element:

> [`remove` Element for `configSections` (General Settings Schema)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309404%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Actually we can remove individual item like 

<remove name="jsonSerialization">

but we can't remove "Sectiongroup" like this.

<remove name="system.web.extensions">. This won't work and this is the main problem.

Comment: @farrukh - can you post an example of how you're using this.